# How to get variable from public function to another function?

Tags: php, function, variables

Hey guys I am trying to figure something out for my streaming site. The only thing I need is that one variable out of another function.

I need to get the `$vsurl` from the method ajax() to another (public static function). 
I tried return and global but I get the error:

> Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Call to undefined function ajax()

for example with global it would be:

```
public function ajax(){
    global $vsurl;
    if($post_id && $play_nm){
        // Get post meta
        switch ($post_ty) {
            case 'movie'
                $vsurl = $this->checkForMovie1( $postmeta );
                break;
            case 'tv':
                $vsurl = $this->checkTv1( $postmeta );
                break;
        }
```

And then I would write ajax(); where I needed the variable. I left a few lines of code out, because they are for sure not the problem. This is where I am calling it to. Heres the full code: http://txt.do/16gsl

```
public static function viewer($post, $type, $players, $trailer, $size, $views, $ads = false, $image = false){
    ajax();
    $html .="<h2>".__d('<a href="//videospider.in/getvideo?key=idlIJqJKfi8VzbQT'.$vsurl.'">Alternative Player</a>')." <span id='playernotice' data-text='{$views}'>{$views}</span></h2>"
```

I am a coding noob so it could be the simplest mistake ever.

Comment: So show us HOW you are calling this method? I assume this is a class method??

Comment: Actually it looks like you need to have a quick read about **Variable Scope** or it could be that what you left out may explain these issues??

Comment: **I left a few lines of code out** Maybe that was not a good idea, can you show us all the relevant code please. See [Minimal, Complete and Verifiable Example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) requirements

Comment: _“And then I would write ajax(); where I needed the variable.”_ - that would be correct for a stand-alone function named `ajax`. But you don’t appear to have that here, you have a public _method_ of some class.

Comment: @RiggsFolly i tried to return it but it didnt work, I got the same error. I think Cbroe is right, but what would be the right way to call the variable out of a public method? I could post the whole code, but I am pretty sure it doesnt has anything to do with it. As it works as a standalone and I am only trying to add a code for my own preferences.

Comment: Your error is saying that you have not instantiated the class or if you have it is not in scope where you are calling it. So show us where you call this method

Comment: Is the `ajax()` method in the same class as the `viewer()` method?

Comment: Yes I think, its in the same file. (You must be raging about my not available knowledge- sorry)

Answer (score 0):

The error tells you that `ajax` is undefined. Since you try to use it from a `static function`, this is the expected behavior. You have a `class`, which has `static functions` and instance-level `functions`. `static functions` are the abilities of the `class`, instance `functions` are the abilities of instances of the `class`. You cannot call instance-level functions from a `static functio`n in the manner of

```
$this->ajax()
```

because `static` functions are agnostic to instances. You can make `ajax` `static` and then the other `static function` will see it via `self::ajax()` (assuming they are in the same `class`). Or, you can make the other `function` instance-level by removing the keyword **static** before its name, so it will see `ajax` from the other `function`, again, assuming that they are in the same `class`.

You can do somehing of the like of

```
$vsurl = $this->ajax();
```

assuming that you are in an instance-level context and that `ajax` ends with

```
return $vsurl;
```

You do not need `global`, it's an anti-pattern. You can work with `global`, nothing stops you, but it's an approach frequently frowned upon.

EDIT

You attempt to call `ajax` in the form of

```
ajax();
```

in your `static` method. This is incorrect, because your `ajax` `function` is not a standard `function`, you need to specify the instance or `class` this `function` belongs to, try the following:

```
public function viewer($post, $type, $players, $trailer, $size, $views, $ads = false, $image = false){
    $vsurl = $this->ajax();
    //Make sure that $html is properly initialized
    $html .="<h2>".__d('<a href="//videospider.in/getvideo?key=idlIJqJKfi8VzbQT'.$vsurl.'">Alternative Player</a>')." <span id='playernotice' data-text='{$views}'>{$views}</span></h2>";
}
```

and make sure that the value is returned:

```
public function ajax(){
    $vsurl = "some default value";
    if($post_id && $play_nm){
        // Get post meta
        switch ($post_ty) {
            case 'movie'
                $vsurl = $this->checkForMovie1( $postmeta );
                break;
            case 'tv':
                $vsurl = $this->checkTv1( $postmeta );
                break;
        }
    }
    return $vsurl;
}
```

and remember to instantiate your `class` before you call `viewer`.

Comment: Thanks first of all. So I tried it as you said and I got the error: Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Using $this when not in object context in ... what does that mean?

Comment: @Dannysea You can only use $this if you are NOT in a static function, but an instance function. This means that you haven't removed the static keyword before viewer, so do this change: public static function viewer -> public function viewer

Comment: @Dannysea please edit your question, paste your whole class and then let me know about it here in the comment section. Without seeing your code it's difficult to help you.

Comment: @Dannysea it should not throw the same error. Can you share the full stack trace of the error? Also, do you use some server caching tools, like Cloudflare?

Comment: Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Using $this when not in object context in /home/hdkinoe3/domains/hdkino.eu/public_html/wp-content/themes/dooplay233_gdrive_vs/inc/doo_player.php:241 - I use WP Fastest Cache. I cant share the full stacktrace because its too long. But the demo website that I am using is: hdkino.eu you can see there.

Comment: @Dannysea I need to know which line is the error thrown at. If it's thrown in viewer, then clearly your viewer function is still static and you should clear the server cache. If it's thrown elsewhere, then it's a different problem, even if the exception message is similar.

Comment: It is thrown in the viewer function, but even after I cleared the cache its still there. http://www.hdkino.eu/?movies=star-wars-the-rise-of-skywalker

Comment: @Dannysea are you sure you have cleared the server cache? No offence, sometimes we get confused and clear the browser cache, thinking that we have cleared the server cache. This specific error should never happen in viewer function unless it's static. So, for some reason the change is not applied.

Comment: Yes I deleted every file out of the cache folder. And still the same message. Btw thanks for helping me figure this out.

Comment: @Dannysea you are more then welcome. We have figured out what the issue is, but for some reason it is not solved yet. Can you remove (temporarily) the line where you call ajax from viewer and tell me what the error is then?

Comment: When I remove it, there's no error. Maybe that way is just not working, isnt there any other possibility to call that variable. For example with $GLOBALS or something

Comment: @Dannysea that's possible, but it's such a bad practice that I discourage you from taking that route. I guess that something makes viewer static again. Is (new DooPlayer())->ajax() running at all?

Comment: What do you mean?

Comment: @Dannysea I am wondering whether you are able to instantiate your class called DooPlayer and call its ajax method. If not, then something is overriding all your changes before they are executed.

Comment: Yes its possible, I got an error from it :D class DooPlayer not found

Comment: @Dannysea that's very strange.

Comment: @Dannysea in that case you will need to make sure that ajax is static.